# Delete one of the stored real objects android

Tags: android, realm

I would like to delete one of the stored realm objects. But I keep getting error.

```
val realm = Realm.getInstance(this)
        val allUsers = realm.where(User::class.java).findAll()
        val deletedDependent = realm.where(User::class.java).equalTo("id",deleteDependentData.dependentUUID).findFirst()

        try {
            realm.beginTransaction()
            deletedDependent.removeFromRealm()
            realm.commitTransaction()
        } catch (e: RealmException) {
            info("Error deleting realm object=>${e.message}")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Log says, `Could not find class 'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$1', referenced from method io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.from`

if I use removeLast, it complains that remove is not supported. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Overcame this issue by adding RxAndroid to my project dependencies.

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'

Comment: You don't have to add RxAndroid if you aren't using Rx, you just have to create a dummy object as specified here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind

Answer (score 0):

```
@RealmClass
public abstract class RealmObject implements RealmModel {

    /**
     * Deletes the object from the Realm it is currently associated to.
     * <p>
     * After this method is called the object will be invalid and any operation (read or write) performed on it will
     * fail with an IllegalStateException.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the corresponding Realm is closed or in an incorrect thread.
     * @see #isValid()
     */
    public final void deleteFromRealm() {
        deleteFromRealm(this);
    }
......

}
```

This may helps you.. If the answer is not useful then please revert back.